# How to minimize full ms-access window in vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have some code to minimize like `docmd.minimize` but it does not work.

Please let me know how to minimize whole window of access in vba?

Answer (score 3):

Almost, but not quite.

The one you're looking for is `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMinimize` (minimize the Access window)

Also:

`DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize`

`DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppRestore`

Comment: Thank u for for answear.but i have a problem when i change popup propertice form  to yes this code dont work,how i can fix it??

Comment: @user1915069 I just test (Access 2010) and had no problem using the same command on a Popup window.

Comment: I use ms access 2010.did not work?